# Mithril show component on button click

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I have to developp an Single Application Page, i choose Mithril.

I need to render a component on button click, this is my code :

```
var accountView = {
    controller: function (data) {
        return {
            showOtherPage: function () {
                ??? how to render an other component ?
            }
        }
    },
    view: function (ctrl) {
        return [
            m("button", { onclick: ctrl.showOtherPage }, "Account")
        ];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Mithril's routing functionality and want to show a whole new page, then you can use a link rather than using a button. (Personally, this is how I normally anticipate handling these scenarios.) eg,

```
m("a[href=/otherPage]", { config: m.route }, "Account")
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/11qjx341/

(Alternatively, you could also call `m.route('/otherPage')` within the `showOtherPage` function if a link is not appropriate for some reason.)

Or, if you're not using Mithril's routing (eg if you're using `m.mount`), but still want to render a whole new page, you might want to call `m.mount` with the new view to have it rendered. eg

```
m.mount(document.body, otherView);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/91g9db6n/

As a third option, if your new view is actually meant to coexist with the current page, you can have a component that's shown or hidden based on state. eg

```
return [
    m("button", { onclick: ctrl.showModal.bind(ctrl, !showModal) }, showModal ? "Hide Account" : "Account")
    , showModal ? m.component(OtherView) : null
];
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mk27tfq1/

Comment: I think the 3rd option is the best. One of the really powerful things to understand about Mithril is the fact that it's less about "now do a thing" and more about "change the state such that things happen". The view expresses all the possible states the DOM can be in, and changes conditions such that the are met.

Comment: Yeah it's a pattern I use a lot, but I wasn't sure if I read the question correctly (the use of the word "page" vs "component" :-) ), and the use of the word "page" made me lean towards using routing, whilst the question itself refers to rendering a component, and hence option 3 sounds good :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Bryce.

The fist command is good for me, but tell me if i'm wrong, i loose the benefit of the route command who loads all the components at startup.

So i'll try to use the second option, a link with an image to simulate a button.

Comment: But with a link can i control user input to eventually stay on the accountView because user input are wrong ?

Comment: If you're retrieving user input, then I'd consider using a form with an `onsubmit` that executes the functionality you're after. IME it's simple to use HTML5 validation rules (eg `required` attributes, etc) in a lot of scenarios to handle all the validation processing for you (because the `onsubmit` won't even fire if the form's invalid). Alternatively (eg if the validation is more complicated), I'd consider using a `button` with `{ disabled: !ctrl.isValid(), onclick: func }` type check (again, because you know the function (`func`) will never fire if the `isValid` function is falsy).

Comment: Ps, (again, still not sure about page vs component): if your `otherPage` exists as it's own "page"; I'd probably do something like `m('form', { onsubmit: (e) => { e.preventDefault(); m.route('/otherPage') } })`; whereas if it's more like the "component" (eg a modal), then I'd do `m('form', { onsubmit: (e) => { e.preventDefault(); ctrl.showModal(true) } })`. I'd be inclined to treat it more like a "component" if it uses the user input from the current page.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i finaly find how to control user input and stay in accountView, i use return false;